# libvirt/kvm/qemu: Is it possible to boot a Windows guest into safe mode?

Tags: windows, kvm, libvirt, safe-mode

I want to get Windows guest boot info, but I find the only way is to start windows in safe mode, and then there will be some file `ntbtlog.txt` under C:\Windows.

Within kvm/libvirt, is it possible to run into Windows safe mode? How to?

Answer (score 0):

libvirt/kvm don't need anything special in this regard - activating safe mode is something the guest OS determines. Specifically when the guest starts you need to press F8 in the graphical console to bring up the windows boot menu to activate safe mode per these instructions

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17419/windows-7-advanced-startup-options-safe-mode